# WPF hosting winforms control - height only being recalculated on window or control resize

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have an application window that is running on WPF. Inside of this window I have a tab item which is a WPF UserControl (the Interpreter tab shown below). Inside of this Usercontrol I have a dockpanel which contains a last child of Grid, which contains the middle part of the control below (the hexbox, the grid splitter, and the treeview on the right).

[image]

The Hexbox is an instance of Be.winforms.hex.hexbox, which is a winforms control. There is no WPF hexbox that I have found that is an acceptable substitute (I've tried several). So this control is embedded inside of a WinFormsHost:

```xml
<Grid Margin="0,1,0,-1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="220" MaxWidth="718" Width="285" Name="HexboxColumnDefinition" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--<control:HexEditor Name="Interpreter_HexBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" BytePerLine="4" AllowAutoHightLighSelectionByte="False" StatusBarVisibility="Collapsed" AllowDeleteByte="True" AllowExtend="True" />-->
    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   Name="Interpreter_Hexbox_Host" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <hb1:HexBox MinBytesPerLine="4" MaxBytesPerLine="16" ColumnInfoVisible="True" LineInfoVisible="True" Font="Courier New,10" BoldFont="Consolas,10" StringViewVisible="True" SelectionStartChanged="hb1_SelectionChanged" SelectionLengthChanged="hb1_SelectionChanged" VScrollBarVisible="True">
        </hb1:HexBox>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
...
```

When the window is initialized, the hexbox is empty. There is no data in it. What I am seeing is that when the hexbox data is populated by selecting an item on the left, the control sets its height to the height that would be required to show all of the data (which sometimes is thousands of bytes - beyond the height of the application).

This causes the scrollbar to not appear, which by default to the end user means you can't scroll. I also cannot programatically scroll to a selected byte (by clicking on things on the right tree), as there is no actual scrolling.

However, if I drag the gridsplitter so the control resizes (or resize the window), the size is recomputed and the scrollbar appears.

[image]

I cannot figure out how to trigger this behavior properly automatically so users don't have to do this. It is pretty annoying as it comes up pretty often. I am not sure if I am supposed to bind something, but I can't figure out how these two items work.

I have my code for this commit here, with the line highlighted: https://github.com/Mgamerz/ME3Explorer/blob/05309979cdebaecea4005620bacd855d20248458/ME3Explorer/Interpreter/InterpreterWPF.xaml#L73

I am not sure how to work around this. It is very frustrating to have to always resize, and I can't figure out how to call the resize code. I suppose I could just resize the grid splitter position, but that seems like a real hack, is there a more proper way?

Comment: Could you wrap the host in a `ScrollViewer`? Not sure it will fix your issue but seems worth a shot

Comment: Just tested it. It adds a scroll bar, but it doesn't seem to enable scrolling (just adds a second scroll bar, if i widen the hexbox it adds its own scrollbar). I am not sure if the control is extending too far or if the panel it is part of is not showing the scrollbar. This issue does not seem to occur in the winforms version of this window, only in the hosted version in wpf. The way it seems to act is that the content is all visible and not needing scrolling, when it actually does.

Comment: @Mgamerz Could the problem be reproduced with some easy steps and some builtin controls without any 3rd party controls?

Comment: I could look into trying to make one. I have the source for hexbox in my project, it is fairly concise, consisting of a VScrollBar (which is added to the control is the ScrollBarVisible property is set, and removed when set to false) and the content area. Looking at the code, I do not see how it sets the scroll bar visibility, however I have not tested with other controls. I just tested doing +/- 1 width to the winform control, it doesn't make it appear. However if I call UpdateLayout between the +/- on the winforms host, it corrects the scrollbar and works.